# Object orientation in Django. What is the best practice in this case?

Tags: python, django, object, orientation

The case is the following:
A user can comment on an article. So I have a Comment model, an Article Model and a User model.
These are my two ideas two implement:

-The first case is to define a method in the Article model called add_comment(user, comment)

```
class ArticleModel(models.Model):
    ...
    def add_comment(self, user, comment):
        # Here I instantiate a new Comment object asociated to this article (self), the passed user and comment as parameter, and then save it.
```

-And the second case is to define a method in the User model called comment_article(article, comment):

```
class UserModel(models.Model):
    ...
    def comment_article(self, article, comment):
        # Here I instantiate a new Comment object asociated to this user (self), the passed article and comment as parameter, and then save it.
```

Which one is the best practice to implement a good object orientation in those cases?

Answer (score 0):

On [enter link description here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/misc/design-philosophies/), they mention *Loose coupling*.

> The various layers of the framework shouldn’t “know” about each other unless absolutely necessary.

This can be applied to you models. In this case I think your ArticleModel should handle it's relation with the UserModel, since the user is a something that can (and should) live without other models, but the same cannot be said about articles that have comments made by users.